# Hide body background when mobile device detected

Tags: css

```
body {
background:url(../img/background_leftside.png), url(../img/background_rightside.png);
background-position:left top, right top;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-attachment:fixed;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I want that when my site is accessed from a smartphone or tablet the background to 
not be displayed.

Comment: Do you want to detect for mobile devices or do you want to detect the screen resoultion? First needs js, second one needs media querys.

Answer (score 2):

Use `media queries` concept to do this.

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* Large screens ----------- */

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Only problem on media querys is that they cannot detect a small desktop browser like on a small tablet pc. Therefore you need some js.

Answer (score 0):

Either use CSS `media querys` or use javascript like this to detect für mobile devices:

```
var isMobileDevice      = false;

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    isMobileDevice = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|webOS)/);
}
```

After that use isMobileDevice to check and remove die image like:

```
if(isMobileDevice) {
    jQuery('body').css('background', 'none')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the css code in media query

snippet will only show the result on full width not for less than 769px. i.e., from the tablet size.

```css
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  body{
    background:url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg), url(../img/background_rightside.png);
    background-position:left top, right top;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
}
```